# How to add JavaScript just for one specific page?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using Zurb Foundation in my project and it is very convenient. But I'm confused that how can I add my own JavaScript which is just for a specific page's DOM when that page is loading.

I used a third-party chart lib in a page's partial and I must initial the chart container with some JavaScript. These JavaScripts can not be combined to the final `app.js` because other pages don't contain the chart container `div`. So can any one give me some advice?

**Edit:** The following is my project structure.

```
src/
├── assets
│   ├── img
│   │   └── x.jpg
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   ├── draw.js
│   │   └── xcharts.js
│   └── scss
│       ├── app.scss
│       ├── news.scss
│       └── _settings.scss
├── data
├── layouts
│   └── default.html
├── pages
│   ├── news.html
│   └── template.html
├── partials
│   └── news-header.html
└── styleguide
    ├── index.md
    └── template.html
```

I tried adding my JavaScript code just after my chart container but I can't because it used jQuery.Assuming that my JavaScript is the `draw.js`. The gulp will auto merge the `draw.js` to the `app.js` which is for every page. If I just include the `draw.js` to my page but which page I should prevent the gulp auto merge the `draw.js` and `xcharts` to the `app.js` and then add a script tag to somewhere of the page.But how?
 Is there a way that is convenient to add scripts that are out of the Foundation framework? Is there a method like the html template partial's behavior?

Comment: Why can't you just add another script tag and include it only on that page?

Comment: @ColinMarshall I added my project structure and some details.

Comment: Thanks, that info helped. For future reference, include information like how you are using Foundation in your project (i.e. a Foundation template, bower, npm, etc.) and the version # to get an answer quicker. Foundation is robust and can be used in many different ways so it helps to know specifics, although I was able to figure out how you were using it by looking at your folder structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the looks of your folder structure I am assuming the "flavor" of Foundation 6 you are using is the Foundation Zurb Template.

1. Move all scripts you want to use on one page only to `src/assets/js/single-page`
2. Open up `src/layouts/default.html`
3. Find the line: `<script src="{{root}}assets/js/app.js"></script>`
4. After that line, insert the following code:

```html
{{#ifpage 'news'}}
  <script src="{{root}}assets/js/single-page/draw.js"></script>
  <script src="{{root}}assets/js/single-page/charts.js"></script>
{{/ifpage}}
```

This will only include those scripts on the page named `news`.

The scripts also need to be excluded in `config.yml` so that they aren't included in `app.js`. Add `"!src/assets/js/single-page/**/*"` to the javascript paths towards the bottom:

```
# Paths to your own project code are here
    - "src/assets/js/!(app).js"
    - "!src/assets/js/single-page/**/*"
    - "src/assets/js/app.js"
```

Change the javascript task in `gulpfile.babel.js` to this:

```js
function javascript() {
  // Insert this section before the return statement
  gulp.src('src/assets/js/single-page/**/*.js')      
  .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.uglify()
    .on('error', e => { console.log(e); })
  ))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/js/single-page'));

  return gulp.src(PATHS.javascript)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.babel())
    .pipe($.concat('app.js'))
    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.uglify()
      .on('error', e => { console.log(e); })
    ))
    .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/js'));
}
```

Now any JS files you stick in the `single-page` directory will be copied to the `dist` directory and excluded from `app.js`.

For more about the template system used in the Foundation templates, see the [Panini](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/panini.html) section of the [Foundation Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/).

Comment: What you stated above adds a script tag to the `news` page. But the gulp will also `concat` the `draw.js` to the final `app.js` and the whole `src/assets/js/` folder will be watched and continued to be piped to the `dist/assets/js/app.js` when it has any change. So firstly I must mask the `draw.js` from the gulp's building process and then copy it to the `dist` folder using another `gulp src pipe` command. I googled and found the gulp's `streamqueue` can append a pipe to a pipe but I got the `streamqueue not defined` error.  So how can achieve this goal?

Comment: How can I configure the `gulpfile.babel.js` or the `config.yml` in a good way? the `copy` or the `javascript` function of `gulpfile.babel.js`? and how? or just add a function of my own?

Comment: The following is what I did and it works: firstly I added `- "src/assets/js/!(draw).js"` to the `javascript PATH` in the `config.yml` and then add `gulp.src('src/assets/js/draw.js').pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/js'));` just before the line of its return statement of the `javascript` function of`gulpfile.babel.js`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GuisongHe answer updated with what you did, but changed so that you don't have to continually add single page js files to `config.yml` since they will reside in their own directory.